# Зачем в Generic нужен конструктор?

Tags: java, generics

Вот пример кода

```
public  class Main<T> {

public T value;

  private Main(T value){
    this.value = value;
}


private T getT() {
    return value;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main<Integer> intobject = new Main<>(1);
    Integer valueinteger = intobject.getT();
    System.out.println(valueinteger);
}
}
```

Почему здесь необходим конструктор? Почему без него нельзя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему нельзя? Можно и без конструктора:

```
public  class Main<T> {
    public T value;

    private T getT() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Main<Integer> intObject = new Main<>();
        intObject.value = 1;
        final Integer valueInteger = intObject.getT();
        System.out.println(valueInteger);
    }
}
```

P.S. Вообще-то обычно делают наоборот - переменная приватная, а геттер - публичный.